# Cronometro regressivo mas que quando chega a zero recomeça?

Tags: microsoft-excel, timer, count

Adaptei um cronômetro regressivo que encontrei aqui na net e adaptei ao que pretendo. É para ser usado numa prova de ciclismo e numa etapa de contra-relógio em que os ciclistas partem de 2 em 2 minutos. Ele funciona mas não consigo fazer o *loop* para que quando chega a zero (00:00:00), lança na folha a hora da partida e volta iniciar com o tempo selecionado na `combobox1`, que por sua vez tem varias hipóteses de escolha, mas uma vez escolhido é sempre o mesmo.

Outra coisa que gostaria que fizesse era quando falta-se 5 segundos para o fim a cada segundo emitisse um som.

Abaixo o código no form e no módulo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No form

```
 Option Explicit
 Dim T
 Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 TextBox1.Value = ComboBox1.Value
 End Sub
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 T = Time
 'Definir qde de tempo a regredir
 If RegressivoForm3.ComboBox1.Value = "00:00:10" Then
 Fim = Time + TimeValue("00:00:10")
 End If
 If RegressivoForm3.ComboBox1.Value = "00:00:15" Then
 Fim = Time + TimeValue("00:00:15")
 End If

 Application.Run "StartTimer"
 End Sub
 Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 'Para que se carregar no parar com o crono parado não dar erro
 On Error Resume Next
 'Para o crono
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Update", , False
 End Sub
 Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
 TextBox1.Value = ComboBox1.Value
 End Sub
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 With ComboBox1
 .AddItem "00:00:10"
 .AddItem "00:00:15"
 End With
 End Sub
 Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
 StopTimer
 End Sub

 No modulo

 Option Explicit
 Dim T
 Public Fim As Date, Num As Long, ComboBox1 As Long
 Sub StopTimer()
 'Encerra a cronometragem
 On Error Resume Next
 Application.OnTime T, Procedure:="Update", Schedule:=False
 End Sub
 Sub StartTimer()
 'Verifica diferença dos segundos
 If Time < Fim Then
 'Atualiza a cada 1 segundo
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Update"

 Else
 'Chama rotina para encerrar contagem
 Application.Run "StopTimer"
 'Quando chega aos 5 seg muda a cor para vermelho


 'Verifica se o dorsal já partiu
 If Range("D" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value <> "" Then
 MsgBox "Este dorsal ja iniciou a etapa!", vbCritical, "Erro"""
 RegressivoForm3.TextBox2.SetFocus
 End If

 If Range("D" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "" Then
 'Seleciona a celula e poe o tempo
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
 ActiveCell.Value = Time
 'Seleciona a linha e poe cor verde
 Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row), Selection.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 3)).Select
 With Selection
 .Interior.ColorIndex = 4
 End With
 End If
 End If

 End Sub
 Sub Update()

 RegressivoForm3.TextBox1 = Format(Fim - Time, "hh:mm:ss")

 Call StartTimer

 End Sub

 Sub meuform()
 RegressivoForm3.Show
 End Sub
```

Comment: Você pode fornecer o arquivo de exemplo?

Comment: Sou novo aqui não consigo inserir o arquivo. Como faço?

Comment: Pelo SO não é possível, mas você pode colocar o link em alguma pasta pública de dropbox, google drive, etc.